# Moving a number of tables from one database to another using a linkedserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

Moving one table at the time is no problem, I have the query for that, but I have a larger number of tables that I will need to extract several times, so I would like a script that did it for me.

Basically it's this code I need in sql but don't know how to write it. Executed from the DB they should end up in.

```
for @TableName in ('TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE3')

SELECT *
INTO SCHEMA.@TableName 
FROM 
OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER,'SELECT * FROM @TableName')

End
```

Comment: can't do it. just script out the tables you need.

Comment: How do you mean script out?

Comment: create a sql script that will transfer all of your tables. either save it as a stored procedure or a regular sql script, then execute it whenever you need to transfer data. If it is regularly scheduled, create a sql job to call the stored procedure on a regular basis to move the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cursor fom a list of your tables and loop through that. Then to add in more tables, you just add them to list_of_tables:

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(128);
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max);

declare d cursor for 
select tablename from (
select 'Table1' as tablename
union
select 'Table2' as tablename
union
select 'Table3' as tablename ) as list_of_tables;

open d;
    fetch next from d into @tablename;
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        set @sqlquery = 'SELECT * INTO SCHEMA.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' 
                    FROM 
                    OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER,''SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)+ ''');'
        exec (@sqlquery);
        fetch next from d into @tablename;
    end;
close d;
deallocate d;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, somehow it seems it doesn't find the query or stored procedure, message I get: 
 @sqlquery
 Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * INTO SCHEMA.TABLE1
                    FROM 
                    OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER,'SELECT * FROM TABLE1');'.
 Msg: 2812, Level: 16, State: 62, Procedure: , Line: 21

Not been able to find out why, any idea?

Comment: Ooops, I forgot the brackets in the line exec (@sqlquery); Answer edited - give that a go!

Comment: Just a quick warning: this will only copy the table structure. None of the constraints (defaults, foreign keys, ...), indices or primary keys will be copied.

Comment: Updated to include `quotename`

Comment: Thanks alot! You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

You can generate script from `sys.objects`

Such as:

```
SELECT 
        'SELECT * 
         INTO Schema.' + SO.name + '
         FROM 
            OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER, ''SELECT * FROM ' + SO.name + ''')
         '
    FROM 
        OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER
                    , 'SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = ''U''') SO
```